# Adjusting the size of several layers of 2d animation slightly crook the look

Tags: 2d

I'm trying to make an animation for school project. I made a face from several layers because I'm still very new to it and I'm drawing it using pc . When I tried to adjust the size of the whole thing, the face became slightly crooked and out of place. Here's the example:

[image: This is the face before I change the size.]
^This is the face **before** I change the size.

[image]
^This is the face **after** I changed the size.

Is there any way to prevent it? Anyway thanks in advance.